# HotTowel Angular and Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hottowel

Starting to look at HotTowel templates for AngularJS and all those "why" questions pops into my mind. I have cleared some of them, but couldn't clear this. I.e. the use of "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)" for controllers. Below is the code from "shell.js"

```
    (function () { 
        'use strict';

        var controllerId = 'shell';
        angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
            ['$rootScope', 'common', 'config', shell]);

        function shell($rootScope, common, config) {
            var vm = this;
      //rest of the code omitted
```

I can't figure out why IIFE is used here. One reason could be if we don't use IIFE, then

```
var controllerId = "shell"
```

will have global scope (is that correct?). I have tried to remove the IIFE style and obviously it is working with out any issue. I went through [AngularJS Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide) but couldn't find an explanation there. Can someone please explain what benefits we get by following this approach?

P.S. If you think this is not the correct place for this question please point me to the correct place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said it's to prevent adding to global scope. In you above code `controllerId` and the `shell` function will be added to global scope if an IIFE is not used.

There is an explanation in [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#iife):

> Why?: An IIFE removes variables from the global scope. This helps
>   prevent variables and function declarations from living longer than
>   expected in the global scope, which also helps avoid variable
>   collisions.
>
> Why?: When your code is minified and bundled into a single file for
>   deployment to a production server, you could have collisions of
>   variables and many global variables. An IIFE protects you against both
>   of these by providing variable scope for each file.

Comment: So if we don't use this var controllerId = "shell", then we don't need IIFE? Other than declaring the controller ID, what other situations will IIFE would be better in controller declaration?

Comment: ok, one other place is that I have seen in directive declarations,  var app = angular.module('app'); is being used when we need a reference to the app. If not for the local scope with IIFE, then we will have to name app1, app2... a dozen of names to refer the app in directives/Services

Comment: It's the same thing. It's to prevent adding app to global scope. You shouldn't actually use `var app =` because you should only declare one directive per file so there no is no need to refer to refer to app again. This is also mentioned in the [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#definitions-aka-setters).